# Checking whether one polynomial is a factor of another

Tags: polynomials, factorization

Given two polynomials, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, I need to determine whether $f(x)$ is a factor of $g(x)$. Seems simple enough, and the way I initially did it was just checking if $f(x)$ is in a FactorList of $g(x)$:

```
MemberQ[Flatten[FactorList[ g[x] ]][[;; ;; 2]], f[x] ]
```

This almost works, however, when you consider something like $g(x)=x^4-1$ and $f(x)=x^2-1$, it should return true since $g(x) = f(x) (x^2+1)$. However, FactorList gives a list of irreducible polynomials, which doesn't include $x^2-1$.

So, how do I check if one polynomial is a factor of another in Mathematica?

Comment: Check if remainder is zero, as in `In[187]:= PolynomialRemainder[x^4 - 1, x^2 - 1, x]

Out[187]= 0`

Comment: Could also use `PolynomialMod[x^4-1, x^2-1]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> how do I check if one polynomial is a factor of another in
>   Mathematica?

One possibility might be to use `PolynomialRemainder`

```
PolynomialRemainder[x^4-1,x^2-1,x]==0
(*True*)
```

Based on using $\frac{p(x)}{d(x)} = Q(x) + \frac{R(x)}{d(x)}$. Where $R(x)$ is the Remainder and $Q(x)$ is the quotient. So if $d(x)$ is factor of $p(x)$ then the Remainder should be zero.